# How to use teamcity.build.triggeredBy.username property in case when build was triggered by schedule

Tags: teamcity

My case is what I want to send custom email (not notification) to user who run a build. But in case when build was triggered by schedule I want to send the email to the default user (release manager). `teamcity.build.triggeredBy.username` property is good for me except when build was triggered automatically. `teamcity.build.triggeredBy.username` not defined and I got "`%teamcity.build.triggeredBy.username%`" value instead "" as I expected.

What the best way to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing a custom module, what you can do instead is utilize the notifications tab in teamcity

In the notifications tab, there are genreic  notification rules that can be sent. In your case, you can set a notification alert to send a mail to the person who ran/broke the build. There are various options . I would suggest you play with them a bit to figure out which one you need exactly

Answer (score 0):

you can check `teamcity.build.triggeredBy` property: it's always available and will be set to Schedule Trigger. e.g. in `linux-sh`:

```
if [ '%teamcity.build.triggeredBy%' == 'Schedule Trigger' ]; then ...; fi
```